# Location of Single Save Price Indexing Code

Tags: product, magento-1.6, indexing

When you save a product in Magento's backend admin console application, the system will reindex the price information for that product.

Where in the core code does this "single save" product price reindex kick-off and happen?  Is it the same code path at the main price re-indexer?  Or is it somewhere else?

Comment: What version? In CE < 1.4 lots of reindexes were triggered by observer events from CatalogIndex.

Comment: @philwinkle Specifically 1.6.1, but interested in answers from all versions (for the Googles)

Answer (score 2):

I'm using Magento 1.7 and the class "Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Indexer_Price" in the function _registerCatalogProductSaveEvent I see where the single product id is set to be reindexed.

The class "Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Indexer_Price" has a catalogProductSave function. Here it says it is "Processing the product save."  However I'm not sure if this is exactly what you are looking for as these are all directly dealing with the events to reindex the product.

Comment: +1 for useful information, but that doesn't appear to do the actual saving — its just registering an event with information the index processor will use.

Comment: I have updated my original answer to have a bit more detail, and added a separate function, but it is still dealing with the events for reindexing price.

Answer (score 1):

I found the specific method I was looking for in Magento 1.6.  It is

```
#File: app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Product/Indexer/Price.php
function reindexProductIds()
{
    //...
}
```

If you've changed the price during a product save, this is the method that's ultimately called.